# Django Admin shows primary key column twice

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I´m using Django Admin and this shows every field which I want to Edit. But If I select primary key as editable as well, Django Admin shows this fields twice. First One (for checking if I want delete it) and a the same colum at the end (after all columns) with the primary key again but without title for the column.
How can I avoid this last column without lost the editable option for this primary key?

EDITED:

```
--Admin.py--
class table_nameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['field1','field2',]
list_editable = ['field1','field2',]
search_fields = ['field1',]
ordering = ('field2',)
list_per_page = records_Per_Page
```

admin_site.register(table_name, table_nameAdmin)

The Django Admin template looks like:

```
|name_Field1  ||name_Field2            ||no_name                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|values_field1||values_field2_editables||values_field1_editables|
```

Could I show only the two fields as editables?

Comment: please show your effort as well post your code

Comment: have the exact same issue. did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: Finally, I did it by my own. Using pure html and css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try remove first column 'link' to edit page.
Like this:

```
class table_nameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['field1','field2',]
    list_editable = ['field1','field2',]
    search_fields = ['field1',]
    ordering = ('field2',)
    list_per_page = records_Per_Page

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(table_nameAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list_display_links = (None, )
```

Comment: Kind of... I still have the last column without head. But, at least, the first column is editable now.
I mean, I have the three columns yet but the first one is editable as well.

Comment: @EliasMP, the third column is editable too?  Which django version?

Comment: Yep. The third colum is editable as well. Django Version: 1.8.4. Is that the problem? Is there any way to solve it?